# Critical points of $z =(x^2 + y^2)\exp(-(x^2 + y^2))$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find and classify the critical points of the function $z = (x^2 + y^2)e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}$

I've found that the critical points of this function are $(0,0)$ and all the points that satisfies $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. My doubt if that if I need to calculate the determinant of the Hessian matrix or there is a better way to classifiy the points without doing it. 
Since the derivatives of first order are $ 2xe^{-(x^2 + y^2)}(1-x^2-y^2)$ and  $  2ye^{-(x^2 + y^2)}(1-x^2-y^2)$, it would be great if there is another way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the problem doesn't ask you to classify the critical points, only to find them..So you've done that.

Comment: You do recognize that the graph is a figure of revolution about the $z$-axis? So that in some sense the situation is not a two-variable problem, but a one-variable problem?

Comment: @Lubin I just know it is a revolution surface because my teacher said so. I couldn't get this conclusion by myself And I don't know why it is a revolution figure even knowing, now, that it is. How can I recognize that it is a revolution surface? $(x^2 + y^2) $ tell me this?

Comment: @Doc Yes, it does

Comment: Well $(0,0)$ is clearly a minimumm since the function can never be negative.  Now you could consider values of $\frac{(1\pm \epsilon)^2}{e^{(1\pm \epsilon)^2}}$ for small $\epsilon$ and compare these values to $\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: @Giiovanna, so it does.  Thanks.  So much for reading only the heading line.

Comment: It’s a figure of revolution because it’s of the form $z=G(r)$, where $r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$, in other words, the function-value depends only on the distance of $(x,y)$ from the origin. That is exactly what it means for something to be a figure of revolution. (Think of a lathe.)

Comment: @Doc I've been trying doing it but I could not conclude that the function have minimum value at $(x^2 + y^2 = 1)$

Comment: @Lubin thanks! So, if I Find the maximum/minimum points of the curve formed when $y=0$, will be that enough to conclude which points are maximum or minimum?

Comment: Indeed, when $y=0$ and $x\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

$z_x=2xe^{-r^2}(1-r^2),\ z_y=2ye^{-r^2}(1-r^2)$ so that $(0,0),\
 r=1$ are critical points

$z(0,0)=0 $ and $z\geq 0$ so that $(0,0)$ is global minimum

When $|(a,b)|=1,\ f(t)=z(ta,tb) =  t^2e^{-t^2}$, then $ f'(t) =
  2te^{-t^2} (1-t^2)$ so that $f'(1-\epsilon)>0$ and $f'(1+
  \epsilon)>0$ Hence $f(t)$ has local maximum.

So $z (x,y)$ is constant on $r=1$ so that $z$ is local maximum along $r=1$